# updating files periodically within my app. SharedPreferences and what else?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Im updating my android app to download new xml files periodically, once a week or so. from googling, I can see that SharedPreferences will allow me to store a primitive data type which I could use to store an int to represent the date the xml was last updated, such as 10242011. It doesnt mention anything about actually overwriting files in my application though. What would be the best approach to overwrite the xml files in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting old file and writing will cut your time on coding.

I mean in a flow:

`Already have an old file` -> `download new one` -> `delete old one` -> `save new one` -> `use it in your app`

But if you want to have the data from the old one, than you should use method where you just proceed with appending new content where you have stopped previously.

Comment: nope no need append new content. Im just new to dealing with private app data and am not sure what to google in this case

Comment: Either save the content using SharedPrefs (see Tim's answer) or save it somewhere else in the phone (under databases folder [regardless it is not database file] or on sdcard if available or in cached dir) like an ordinary file then load it in the app where is needed and parse it for your purposes. Just mind THAT directory does not require root access when using ur app under device.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Prefs are stored in folder called shared_prefs inside your data/data/ folder. As far as I know using a SharedPreferences.Editor is the only way to manipulate this file under normal conditions. If the device is rooted I imagine you could just save over the top of the xml file though.

You could probably look at the source code for SharedPreferences and make yourself a similar set of objects that allow you to read and manipulate xml files and just write them to your files directory instead of shared_prefs.